# Get data for points within a Mapbox cluster

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have followed [this](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/clustering/) tutorial to do clustering. When a user selects a cluster, I want to get information about the points contained in that cluster. To go with the tutorial, when a user selects a cluster, we get into this section of the code:

```
let clusters = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: rect, styleLayerIdentifiers: ["clusteredPorts"])
let ports = mapView.visibleFeatures(in: rect, styleLayerIdentifiers: ["ports"])
if clusters.count > 0 {
    showPopup(false, animated: true)
    let cluster = clusters.first!
    mapView.setCenter(cluster.coordinate, zoomLevel: (mapView.zoomLevel + 1), animated: true)
}
```

When the user selects a cluster, we get into this `if` statement which is fine. The problem is, `ports` is an empty array, and I would like to get all the ports that are within that selected cluster. Is this possible?